# Mypy does not ignore mpi4py module with syntax error

Tags: mypy, mpi4py

In mypy.ini there is

```
[mypy-mpi4py]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

With this mypy is getting the following error

```
Success: no issues found in 4 source files
s\d\L\.env\lib\site-packages\mpi4py\MPI.pyi:948: error:
invalid syntax  [syntax]
        def __new__(cls, buf: Buffer, /) -> memory: ...
                                       ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
Success: no issues found in 3 source files
```

How can I setup the config to ignore the module ?

Comment: If you use this module, you should be using `python>=3.8`, so just tell `mypy` to use this target version too. I'm not sure that you can ignore `invalid syntax`, because it crashes `mypy` parser and doesn't allow further processing.

Comment: `mypy` is unable to parse AST using Python version you have, there's not much you can do. You can disable looking for stubs in site-packages by running `mypy --no-site-packages ...`, but this will effectively turn off type hints for every third-party dependency installed in site. Or just modify `MPI.pyi` and remove the slash, quick and dirty :-)